# I wanted to send free sms which API have to use in Python

Tags: python

I wanted send free sms using python which API I have to use or any free SMS gateways are present so that I can use in python

Comment: AFAIK there is no reliable free sms gateway service available. You should use your own GSM modem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using Twilio in conjunction with CherryPy for a while to do sms sending and receiving. It does make the message say "Sent from your twilio trial account -", but if you want to remove that eventually it's only a dollar a month and a cent per text. Hopefully this is useful to you.

Comment: but using Twilio its trail account is there any free sms gateway if 10 sms per day also fine

Comment: When working on my project, I did a ton of research and a twilio trial account was the best free option that I could find. And it's very cheap to remove the trial limitations. I don't know of any other solutions.

Comment: No problem. Also, if you know the carrier of the phone that you are sending to, and do not need to receive any messages, have you considered sending an email to the carrier which gets forwarded as a text message? e.g.: http://www.nytimes.com/2011/11/03/technology/personaltech/how-to-send-text-messages-by-e-mail.html?_r=0